# PostgreSQL/PostGIS unable to search inside a rectangle polygon

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I want to be able to query points inside a rectangle surface efficiently. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work.

```
eykache=# SELECT * FROM colonies;
 id |                  location                  
----+--------------------------------------------
  1 | 010100000000000000000000000000000000000000
  2 | 010100000000000000000050400000000000005040
  3 | 010100000000000000000050400000000000000000
  4 | 0101000000000000000000504000000000000050C0
  5 | 0101000000000000000000000000000000000050C0
  6 | 010100000000000000000050C000000000000050C0
  7 | 010100000000000000000050C00000000000000000
(7 rows)

eykache=# SELECT id FROM colonies WHERE ST_Contains(colonies.location, ST_MakeEnvelope(-64, -64, 64, 64));
 id 
----
(0 rows)
```

As you can see the second response is empty.

Comment: Can you show the locations as EWKT?

Comment: How can I do so?

Comment: Here are the locations I added:
[1] at (0, 0)
[2] at (64, 64)
[3] at (64, 0)
[4] at (64, -64)
[5] at (0, -64)
[6] at (-64, -64)
[7] at (-64, 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to reverse the arguments within ST_Contains:

```sql
SELECT id FROM colonies WHERE ST_Contains(ST_MakeEnvelope(-64, -64, 64, 64), colonies.location);
```